# Magento only shows 9 search results per page

Tags: php, search

I am developing in magento

When I perform a search, I 'm getting 9 search results per page.
But in the top bar it shows "12"
http://overpic.net/viewer.php?file=x12x90jyind7m6rjvabsx.png

I need to get 12 results per page.

I know it is used the same block than the category page, but in category page i am getting 12 results per page, as it should be.

I am using Grid mode in both.

I have tried the following:

- Change "Products per Page on Grid Default Value", "Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values" values in System > config > Catalog > Catalog > Frontend

(The category page and search result page  does not obey any value from here, I do not know where they get the current values)
 **Doesn't work**

- Edit xml file:

-app/design/frontend/default/THEME/layout/catalogsearch.xml
with parameter like:

```
<action method="addPagerLimit"><limit>12</limit></action>
<action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>12</limit></action>
```

(still show 9)

**Doesn´t work**

- Find some other xml file containing limitations with this number .
  **I didn´t find**

EXTRA INFORMATION:

- I have installed a custom theme.
- I have Installed this module: https://www.bubbleshop.net/es/magento-elasticsearch.html to use elastic search engine.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the elastic search module?